# why isnt this equal function working

Tags: php, passwords, equals

im trying to make something to change password.

nkode is the new password
gkode is the old password

```
if($_GET[rediger] == 'ja'){
    $nkode = md5($_POST[nkode]);
    $gkode = md5($_POST[gkode]);
    if($nkode !== ''){
        if($gkode !== ''){
            $nukode = $udskrivprofil[Kodeord];
            if($gkode == '$nukode'){
                echo "success";
            } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
        }   
    }
echo "<br>$gkode <br> $nukode";
}
```

both $gkode and $nukode outputs the 100% same, yet i get the fail error... whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if($gkode == '$nukode'){
```

Look at those quotes. You're comparing the contents of `$gkode` against a string which has the characters `$`, `n`, `u`, etc... in it...

Maybe you wanted

```
        if($gkode == $nukode){
```

instead?

Comment: oh silly... i forgot those, what a mistake...

Answer (score 2):

remove quotes from $nukode variable...

```
if($_GET[rediger] == 'ja'){
$nkode = md5($_POST['nkode']);
$gkode = md5($_POST['gkode']);
if($nkode !== ''){
    if($gkode !== ''){
        $nukode = $udskrivprofil[Kodeord];
        if($gkode == $nukode){
            echo "success";
        } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
    }   
}
echo "<br>$gkode <br> $nukode";
}
```